# Android Java - Putting all file names from R.raw into array without manually specifying each

Tags: java, android, media

There are 2 parts to my question but both are related. I have searched all over the place but cannot find a way to put in an array, all file names from R.raw, such as MP3s in string format.

I also want to create new buttons on the fly in Java, as opposed to using the XML files to lay out buttons.

psuedocode:

array[] = put all file names from R.raw into this array with file name;

count = count num of rows in array[];

//I want to be able to do this with that array
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   create new button and assign it a sound(onclick);
   this.button should be placeable anywhere i want without using XML for layout
}

Thanks in advance to any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** You can't.

**Long answer:** `R.raw` and the likes are generated at build time, thus static in your code (you can't dynamically add entries to these objects from your app). Basically, `R` is just a class that looks something like:

```
package com.yourapp;
public class R {
    public class raw {
       public static final int file_1 = 123456; // where 123456 is the address where that file will be found
       public static final int file_2 = 789012;
       // ...
    }
}
```

Thus, there's no way (that I know of) of getting an array of these attributes.

---

I recommend you use the `assets/` directory instead of `R.raw`. This way, you'll be able to use [`AssetManager.list()`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to get a list of files (and the other [`AssetManager`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) functions for actually working with the files).

Comment: Thank you, sir. Forgive me for being an amateur. Just starting to learn Java.

Comment: I also found a great example here.

http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/17/using-assets-in-android/

Comment: @s5Android: If you consider this the correct answer to your question, please click the checkmark to its left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection:

```
Field [] f=R.raw.class.getFields();
for (Field field : f) {
    field.getName();

}
```